# Как выполнить команду из открытой консоли в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Как выполнить команду в открытой консоли **nodejs**, через файл исходного кода  `.js`?

Команды типа `console.log();` не годятся, так как они команды для логирования.

Comment: какие команды вы хотите выполнить в консоли?

Comment: Sergiks - любые. Например help, или gulp -v

Comment: выполнить в контексте открытой в браузере страницы?

Comment: о какой консоли вы говорите? браузера или nodejs?

Comment: @Grundy nodejs -консоли

Comment: @Sergiks я про Node.js  - вопрос поправил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В консоли команды обычно надо набрать и нажать enter - и они выполняются, лично у меня не возникало с этим проблем.

Если вам надо выполнить целый файл как команду консоли, то в nodejs вы можете просто [require](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules) нужный файл и он выполнится. в консоли браузера так просто не выйдет, но смысл действий тот же - можно использовать require.js или получить файл как текст с помощью например ajax или другим способом и просто `eval` его.

Если же вы наборот, хотите из вашего скрипта выполнить команду в консоли, то в node есть [require('child_process').exeс](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback),а в браузере в консоли нет ничего, что не было бы доступно из скрипта (мне на ум приходят разве что какие нибудь расширения браузера, которые выполняются в отдельной песочнице, но для них это утверждение тоже верно - просто у них своя консоль).

Если же вам нужен доступ к своему скрипту из консоли (например для отладки) и вы почему-то не можете до него достучатся - значит он у вас хитрозамкнутый, и надо просто как нибудь добавить возможность добраться к интересующей вас части от глобального объекта (в браузере это `window`, в node - `global`). проще всего тупо нужную функцию/метод/объект запихнуть прямо туда (`window|global .interest_thing = ...` ), я для отладки так часто делаю

Comment: не-не. нужно из скрипта выполнить консольную команду. Как я понимаю......... Алгоритм -   Нужно вписать из скрипта js в консоль команду --- допустим help ----- и выполнить действие на её выполение(enter если писать в ручную)

Comment: Я как раз подумал об этом пока вы писали комментарий и обновил ответ

Comment: немного не понял а как выполнять команду для Node.js. Можно что бы не подключать модуль? 'тут команда для консоли'.exeс - как то так

Comment: это встроенный модуль node js, почему вы не хотите его подключать?

Comment: а где саму команду писать require('child_process').exeс?

Comment: Откройте ссылку, там есть пример. Записывать require('child_process').exeс в переменную не обязательно, можно прямо сразу писать `require('child_process').exec('command arguments',function(error, stdout, stderr){ ... })`